# liballeg.so.4.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux-mint, executable

Its giving me this error when I try to run an executable file. I have tried

`./filename`
in the directory containing it
and

```
ln filename secondpath
cd secondpath
```

nothing seems to work, I checked that the permissions were right.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with finding the program. The program uses a dynamically linked library that it can't find.

What kind of thing is "filename"? If you don't want to tell us what you are running, it makes it kind of hard to help.

The only likely thing I can find is Allegro, a library for video game development. So it looks like your installation is incomplete: most likely, the file called liballeg.so.4.0 needs to be copied into your user libraries area, or downloaded, or the place where it is needs to be added to your LIB_PATH. Or maybe you have a V5 library but a program built for V4. It would be helpful to know what Distro you are on.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the file was 32-bit and my OS was 64-bit. I would have to find a compatible package.